# Group by NAME and YEAR, categorize NAME

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, group-by, aggregate

I have a `FINANCE_SOURCE` table (I think it might be called a *vertical* table):

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
| SOURCE_ID | PROJECT_ID | SOURCE_NAME | AMOUNT | YEAR |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
|       101 |          1 | A           |  10.00 | 2017 |
|       102 |          1 | B           |   5.00 | 2017 |
|       103 |          1 | B           |  15.00 | 2017 |
|       104 |          1 | B           |  70.00 | 2016 |
|       105 |          1 | C           |  30.00 | 2017 |
|       106 |          1 | D           |   1.00 | 2016 |
|       107 |          1 | D           |  20.00 | 2017 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
```

I want to `GROUP BY` the `SOURCE_NAME`, with a separate group for each `YEAR`.

And I want any record where the `SOURCE` is **not** `A` or `B` to be categorized as `OTHER`:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------+
| PROJECT_ID | SOURCE_NAME | AMOUNT | YEAR |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+
|          1 | A           |  10.00 | 2017 |
|          1 | B           |  20.00 | 2017 |
|          1 | B           |  70.00 | 2016 |
|          1 | OTHER       |  50.00 | 2017 |
|          1 | OTHER       |   1.00 | 2016 |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+
```

How can I do this? Performance is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the CASE expression to the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT   PROJECT_ID,
         CASE WHEN SOURCE_NAME = 'A' THEN 'A'
              WHEN SOURCE_NAME = 'B' THEN 'B'
              ELSE 'OTHER'
         END SOURCE_NAME,
         SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT,
         YEAR
FROM     FINANCE_SOURCE
GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, 
         CASE WHEN SOURCE_NAME = 'A' THEN 'A'
              WHEN SOURCE_NAME = 'B' THEN 'B'
              ELSE 'OTHER'
         END,
         YEAR
```